# selecting row with highest value and a join

Tags: mysql, sql, row, highest

Ho can i only fetch the rows with the highest cvID value?

current code

```
SELECT 
  CollectionVersionBlocks.cID,
  CollectionVersionBlocks.cbDisplayOrder,
  CollectionVersionBlocks.cvID,
  btContentLocal.bID,
  btContentLocal.content 
FROM
  CollectionVersionBlocks 
  INNER JOIN btContentLocal 
    ON CollectionVersionBlocks.bID = btContentLocal.bID 
WHERE (CollectionVersionBlocks.cID = 259)
  AND CollectionVersionBlocks.isOriginal = 1 
  AND CollectionVersionBlocks.arHandle = 'main' 
  AND btContentLocal.content != ''
```

I want to get the row at the bottom (where the cvID value is 10).

This is a test statement for a bigger result set -

I will eventually need a set of results from perset cIDs (CollectionVersionBlocks.cID = 259 OR CollectionVersionBlocks.cID = 260... upto 800)

[image: picture of result]

updated screenshots

1) too few results
2) un grouped results

[image: result2]

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: did you try max(CollectionVersionBlocks.cvID)

Comment: MySQL. Tried max(CollectionVersionBlocks.cvID) but it give me an incorrect join on btContentLocal. It shows bID 349 for some reason

Comment: @danielCrabbe add your desired result set

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid - what is that? Ideally the statement should select the row with cvID = 10.

Comment: If you need one row with highest value you can do so `ORDER BY CollectionVersionBlocks.cvID DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: I actually need a set of results from preset cIDs (CollectionVersionBlocks.cID = 259 OR CollectionVersionBlocks.cID = 260... upto 800)

Answer (score 2):

To get the highest row per group *(from your question i assume `cID` as a single group)* you can do so by using a self join on the maxima of your desired column by using additional condition in in your third join i.e `ON(c.cID=cc.cID AND c.cvID=cc.cvID)`

```
SELECT 
  c.cID,
  c.cbDisplayOrder,
  c.cvID,
  b.bID,
  b.content 
FROM
  CollectionVersionBlocks  c
  INNER JOIN btContentLocal b
    ON (c.bID = b.bID)
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT cID, MAX(cvID) cvID FROM CollectionVersionBlocks GROUP BY cID) cc
  ON(c.cID=cc.cID AND c.cvID=cc.cvID)
WHERE (c.cID = 259)
  AND c.isOriginal = 1 
  AND c.arHandle = 'main' 
  AND b.content != ''
```

and for multiple groups you can just use `WHERE c.cID  IN(259,....800)`

Comment: thanks M Khalid Junaid, that's closer but it seems to exclude some results [see new screenshot]. Its something to do with the 2nd INNER JOIN.

Comment: @danielCrabbe where you have posted screenshot ? and its better if you can provide [**sql fiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) of your sample dataset

Comment: up top. I would do but this data is a mess and has tens of thousands of rows and entries and 150+ tables.

Comment: @danielCrabbe no no you don't need to provide whole data set just a sample dataset the rows you have shown in image will be enough in fiddle, and also these 2 tables not all tables from database

Comment: I can't get them out as SQL as it keeps crashing but tables are fiddled now. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a0d6

Comment: @danielCrabbe without sample dataset i am unable to provide you the exact query without trying with dataset ,but the approach to the highest value per group i have shown already

Answer (score 0):

Try below Query:

```
SELECT CollectionVersionBlocks.cID,CollectionVersionBlocks.cbDisplayOrder,        CollectionVersionBlocks.cvID ,  btContentLocal.bID , btContentLocal.content 
FROM CollectionVersionBlocks
INNER JOIN btContentLocal
ON CollectionVersionBlocks.bID=btContentLocal.bID 
WHERE (CollectionVersionBlocks.cID = 259) 
AND CollectionVersionBlocks.isOriginal=1 AND CollectionVersionBlocks.arHandle ='main'            AND           btContentLocal.content !='' and CollectionVersionBlocks.cID in
(

    SELECT Max(CollectionVersionBlocks.cID)
    FROM CollectionVersionBlocks
    INNER JOIN btContentLocal
    ON CollectionVersionBlocks.bID=btContentLocal.bID 
    WHERE (CollectionVersionBlocks.cID = 259) 
    AND CollectionVersionBlocks.isOriginal=1 AND CollectionVersionBlocks.arHandle   ='main' AND btContentLocal.content !='' )
```

Comment: thanks - tried that but it give me 4 results still. (the high value is from cvID not cID)